# Filter out specific day list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm trying to exclude some specific dates from a GEE script.
Here is the code I'm working on:

```
// Define the asset polygon as a feature collection
var asset_polygon = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-user/assets/mask');

// Define the year of interest
var year = 2022;

// Define a list of dates to exclude
var excludeDates = ['2022-07-11'];

// Load a Sentinel-2 image collection and filter it by year and location
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(asset_polygon)
  .filterDate(year + '-01-01', year + '-12-31')
  .select(['B8', 'B4'])
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-07-11').not())
  .map(function(image) {
    // Compute NDVI for each image
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
    // Add acquisition date as a band to the image
    var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYYMMdd');
    var dateBand = ee.Image(ee.Number.parse(date)).toInt().rename('date');
    return image.addBands(ndvi).addBands(dateBand);
  });

// Compute the maximum NDVI and acquisition date for each pixel in the collection
var maxNdvi = sentinel2.qualityMosaic('ndvi');
var acquisitionDate = maxNdvi.select('date');
var maxNdvi2 = sentinel2.qualityMosaic('ndvi').select('ndvi');

// Add the maximum NDVI layer to the map
Map.addLayer(maxNdvi2, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['white', 'green']}, 'Maximum NDVI');

// Export the rasters as single band images to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maxNdvi2,
  description: 'S2_max_ndvi_' + year,
  folder: 'gee',
  scale: 10,
  region: asset_polygon.geometry()
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: acquisitionDate,
  description: 'S2_acq_date_' + year,
  folder: 'gee',
  scale: 10,
  region: asset_polygon.geometry()
});
```

Ideally I'd like to use a list of days to exclude (lines 7 and 8) but I don't know how to add it as a list and at the moment I'm not using this variable.

However, I tried filtering it directly using [ee.Filter.not](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefilternot) in line 15

```
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-07-11').not())
```

This is not running into any error but it doesn't filter this date either. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `ee.Filter.date()` docs:

> **-start (Date|Number|String):**
>
> The start date (inclusive).
>
> **-end (Date|Number|String, optional):**
>
> The end date (exclusive). Optional. If not specified, a 1-millisecond range starting at 'start' is created.

So, when you only specify start, you get a 1-millisecond range. That's why `ee.Filter.date('2022-07-11')` doesn't match anything.

A convenient trick, that's not very obvious from the above docs, is to use `ee.Date.getRange()` as the only argument to the date filter. The below snippiet shows how you can combine a dynamic number of date filters.

```
var excludeDates = ['2022-07-11']
var dateFilters = excludeDates.map(function (date) {
  return ee.Filter.date(ee.Date(ee.String(date)).getRange('day')).not()
})
var filter = ee.Filter.and.apply(null, dateFilters)
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterBounds(asset_polygon)
  .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).getRange('year'))
  .filter(filter)
```

A minor note, you might want to switch to `COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED`:

> After 2022-01-25, Sentinel-2 scenes with PROCESSING_BASELINE '04.00' or above have their DN (value) range shifted by 1000. The HARMONIZED collection shifts data in newer scenes to be in the same range as in older scenes.